# cs50 Scrabble game

Tags: c, cs50, scrabble

I'm doing the cs50 scrabble, for some reason it only returns numbers instead of telling me which player wins. I know I must have screwed up somewhere in my `for` loop, but I can't locate the problems:( Also I added `int i` and `int n` in the `compute_score` function because it keeps saying undeclare identifiers, I don't understand because I think they are within the scope of `for` loop. Noobie here, please advise!

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("Player1 wins!\n");
    }
    else if (score1 == score2)
    {
        printf("Ties!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Player2 wins!\n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    // TODO: Compute and return score for string
    int tem_point[] = {};
    int m; 
    int score = 0;
    int i;
    int n;
    for (i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        //Turning to ascii number, "A...Z" correspond "65...90", "a...z" correspond "97...122"
        m = get_int("%i", word[i]);
        //Comparing ascii numbers to decide whether upper case, lower case or not characters
        //Calculate index corresponding to POINTS array and assign points to characters 
        //If not character, get zero point
        if (m < 65 || (m > 90 && m < 97) || m > 122)
        {
            tem_point[i] = 0;
        }
        //If upper case 
        else if (m >= 65 && m <= 90)
        {
            tem_point[i] = POINTS[m - 65];
        }
        //If lower case
        else
        {
            tem_point[i] = POINTS[m - 97];
        }
        score += tem_point[i]; 
    }
    return score;
    
}
```

And here's when I run it:

```
~/pset2/ $ make scrabble
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    scrabble.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o scrabble
~/pset2/ $ ./scrabble
Player 1: abc
Player 2: abc1
97
```

Comment: `get_int` - "Prompts user for a line of text from standard input and returns the equivalent int; if text does not represent an int or would cause overflow, user is reprompted." - I think that function does something different from what you expected.

Comment: `int tem_point[] = {};` declares a native `int` array of no length. Later you use it as if it has space for storage, thereby invoking *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Note: if you want the i-th character as a number, then that's just `m = word[i];` You can toss the get_int.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need m = get_int("%i", word[i]); , chars in c are comparable to constants. Directly use word[i]<65 and so on.

Comment: Thanks guys! I took your advice and replaced m with word[i], and declared int temp_point[] on the first line of for loop body, now when I run it, it says segmentation fault, I think there's something wrong with my logic here.

Comment: try "injecting" various `printf()` statements through out the course of your code to see if it does what it wants it to do. I'd certainly put something like `printf("When i is %i, tem_point is %i", i, tem_point[i])` and `printf("The final score is %i", score)`. I am sure the mistake is easy to find this way. Also try taking a break to clear up your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed your program, there were multiple errors.

#### 1. Firstly you don't need to use:

`m = get_int("%i", word[i])`

This is **unnecessary**

#### 2. Dont use a list like temp_points[]

Found this useless, instead just use a simple int value like score and keep adding it.

#### 3. The main error i think you did was using `temp_point[i] = 0`

if you make it 0 at the start, then all the points u had will all go away and be 0

Your new source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("Player1 wins!\n");
    }
    else if (score1 == score2)
    {
        printf("Ties!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Player2 wins!\n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    // TODO: Compute and return score for string
    int m;
    int score = 0;
    int i;
    int n;
    for (i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        //Turning to ascii number, "A...Z" correspond "65...90", "a...z" correspond "97...122"
        //Comparing ascii numbers to decide whether upper case, lower case or not characters
        //Calculate index corresponding to POINTS array and assign points to characters
        //If not character, get zero point
        //If upper case
        if (word[i] > 64 && word[i] < 91)
        {
            score += POINTS[word[i] - 65];
        }
        //If lower case
        if (word[i] > 96 && word[i] < 123)
        {
            score += POINTS[word[i] - 97];
        }
        else {
            score += 0;
        }
    }
    return score;

}
```

## Hope I helped :)